# Gnome Tweaks- Extensions fails to open

Tags: gnome-tweaks

The Tweaks app opens with no problems to me, but when it comes to opening the Extensions app, the app instantly crashes, Ubuntu doesnt even prompt me to report a crash and etc. Restarting the GNOME shell, restarting the whole pc didnt work for me, I tried reinstalling gnome-tweaks several times but nothing. If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Ubuntu Version: "21.10"

GNOME Version: 40.4.0

```
dido@dido:/$ ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions

total 8

drwxrwxr-x 2 dido dido 4096 Feb 20 22:13 .

drwx------ 3 dido dido 4096 Feb 21 00:43 ..

dido@dido:~/linux-wallpaperengine/build$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions

total 20

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 12 23:45 .

-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Oct 12 23:48 ..


drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 12 23:45 ding@rastersoft.com

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 12 23:45 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 12 23:45 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

```
dido@dido:~/linux-wallpaperengine/build$ gnome-shell-extension-prefs
The gnome-shell-extension-prefs program is deprecated.

Run gnome-extensions-app (from the gnome-shell-extension-prefs package)
for extension management, or use the gnome-extensions command line tool.

Extensions can use the ExtensionUtils.openPrefs() method.
dido@dido:~/linux-wallpaperengine/build$
```

```
dido@dido:~/linux-wallpaperengine/build$ ls -al /var/crash
total 21916
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Feb 20 22:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root        4096 Oct 12 23:54 ..
-rw-r-----  1 dido     whoopsie 9561763 Feb 20 19:26 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 dido     whoopsie       0 Feb 20 12:12 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Feb 20 12:12 _usr_bin_gjs-console.1000.uploaded
-rw-r--r--  1 dido     whoopsie       0 Feb 17 13:28 _usr_bin_shotwell.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Feb 17 13:28 _usr_bin_shotwell.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 dido     whoopsie 9444044 Feb 20 22:14 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 dido     whoopsie 3411133 Feb 20 12:13 _usr_share_discord_Discord.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 dido     whoopsie       0 Feb 20 12:13 _usr_share_discord_Discord.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Feb 20 12:13 _usr_share_discord_Discord.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: Better try reinstalling the extensions app if that is the one crashing: `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`

Comment: Forgot to mention this, but I tried this too

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Also go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and see if that works. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema edited.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It looks fine. Open the `terminal` and type `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` and edit the output that appears in the `terminal` into your question. Also show me `ls -al /var/crash`.

Comment: edited again @heynnema

Comment: See my initial answer. It's just a starting place. Report back. What processor do you have?

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and tell me the EXACT make/model of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: my bios version is 1.4.1, my laptop is a dell vostro 3578 with an i7-8550U @heynnema

Comment: @DanailTenev Thanks for the information. Please see the BIOS update in my answer. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing a LOT of crashes besides the `Extensions` app. Let's get a few basics out of the way first...

**Processor**

i7-8550U

**BIOS**

Dell Vostro 3578

You have a very old BIOS version 1.4.1 from Jun 14, 2018. There's a newer BIOS available, version 1.16.0 from Jan 17, 2022, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/vostro-15-3578-laptop/drivers).

**File System Check**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Memory Test**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: ok I did that, my mem test is 4/4.

Comment: @DanailTenev Did you do the BIOS update and the fsck?